# PHP code doesn't work properly

Tags: php, javascript, html

i've recently started to use php and i am trying to load the content of a website that has a list of file names with (.txt)format.Moreover, i have created a function :

```
<?php
//--------------------------
// The function itself
//--------------------------
function LoadSource($siteurl) {

    $arrText = file($siteurl);
    for ($i=0; $i<count($arrText); $i++) {

        $pos = strpos($text . $arrText[$i], "+CUSERR+");
                if ($pos !== false) {
                   echo "The string +CUSERR+ was found in the string";
                      $text = $text . $arrText[$i]." ==> REJECTED";
                      } else {
                               echo "The string +CUSERR+ was not found in the string";
                      $text = $text . $arrText[$i]." ==> ACCEPTED";
                      }

    }

        return $text;
    }
$source = loadSource("http://www.example.com");
echo $source; 

?>
```

what i am trying to do is, First to load the content of that website and then display (Rejected) Beside the txt file name that has (CUSERR) word in it or (Accepted) beside the txt file name that has (CUSACK) word.

Example :

Url : www.example.com

Content :

```
file1.txt Rejected 
file2.txt Accepted
```

Comment: That code won't even execute, because I have no clue what you're doing with that for loop up there, but it's never even closed.

Comment: also to be "perfect xD" use function loadSource not LoadSource.. then i agreed with Braeden, this code is not complete..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this the line you're after?

```
for ($i=0, $j=count($arrText); $i < $j; $i++) {
```

Comment: Thank you Nev Stokes.you can re-check my first post.I have edited my post.Actually the function works fine (just display the content of the website ) which is the list of all files names.

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error here:

```
for ($i=0; $i
```

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer to the question. Please use "add comment" to leave feedback for the author.

Comment: Incorrect. The question is "PHP code doesn't work properly". Syntax errors cause code to work improperly, so it is a valid answer.